# How to align component with button's text, which has drawableLeft

Tags: android

Currently, I have a `TextView`, which I would like to align properly with the Button's text (Not Button itself)

The layout looks something like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is text view"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        tools:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Button Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/flag_za"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

As you can see, the top `TextView` is aligned properly with `Button` itself. However, what I would like is, the `TextView` to be aligned with "BUTTON TEXT".

I was wondering, how can I perform calculation, to determine how much padding required, so that my `TextView` will aligned properly with "BUTTON TEXT"? (Instead of positioning `TextView` to vertical red line, I would like to position `TextView` to vertical blue line)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are able to calculate as you suggest. If you really need it I would create a invisible image with the same size as the flag and then use the same margin+padding as it has in the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your layout and use a RelativeLayout you can achieve this.
The problem with this solution is that you will need to use a custom button and have to know which is bigger height wise (text or icon):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="This is text view"
        tools:textColor="#ff000000"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_text"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_image"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_text"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_image"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_image"
        android:background="#555"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button_image"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/flag_za"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button_text"
        android:text="Button Text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_image"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```